# javascript adding number to getdate

Tags: javascript

```
   const date = new Date("2020-03-20T12:45:52.793Z");
   console.log(date.getDate() + 1);
```

it shows `21` instead of `3`
I'm new in javascript. the operation `+=` does not works

regarding.

Comment: Why should it show 3? The day you have given is 20. 20 + 1 = 21.

Comment: @WaisKamal Sorry I was wrong. I typed getDate instead of getMonth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the operator (`+`, `+=`) used. Instead, it is to do with the function you used. From [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getDate.asp):

> The getDate() method returns the day of the month (from 1 to 31) for the specified date.

See the following snippet:

```js
const date = new Date("2020-03-20T12:45:52.793Z");
console.log(date.getDate());
```

As you can see, `date.getDate()` outputs `20`, the day of the month you specified. So it is no surprise that adding `1` to this value will get you `21`.

---

Given that you expect the output to be `3`, I assume you want to get the month of the date.

To do this, you need to use `getMonth` and not `getDate`.

And as you have already correctly noticed, you need to add `1` to the month number if you want to get the result `3`, because January starts at `0`.

Again, the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp) definition tells you what you need to know:

> The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time.
>
> Note: January is 0, February is 1, and so on.

```js
const date = new Date("2020-03-20T12:45:52.793Z");
console.log(date.getMonth() + 1);
```

Comment: ups. yea that was month sorry